# Potential impact of resetting ColdFusion admin password

Tags: coldfusion

It seems there is [a way to reset the Admin password for a ColdFusion installation](http://devnulled.com/content/2004/02/retrieving-and-resetting-coldfusion-administrator-passwords/).  What are the potential pitfalls to be aware of before doing so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally very few pitfalls to changing the password.

Changing the -- I'm assuming in your case -- only password for ColdFusion Administrator will have the following impact:

1. Prevent anyone else who has the password from accessing the Administrator (duh!)
2. Break any code that uses the adminapi to programmatically control datasources, mappings, etc.

The first is probably not much of a concern I'm assuming.

The second probably only a small concern.  Very few ColdFusion applications use the adminapi since its easier to use the GUI admin!  If you do a search on the code for "adminapi" you can find out if it will effect your applications.